# How do I check if a field already exists in the database?

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose

My problem is about checking if the name or email of a staff already exist in the database. They say its good to do it in the pre update middleware. I tried it but it's not working.

Im passing the (id_of_staff, updatedStaff_info and callback_function) to the update function.

Here's my update function:

```
module.exports.updateStaff = function(id, updatedStaff, callback){
var query = {_id: id};

    Staff.update(query, updatedStaff, callback);
```

}

Everytime the  Staff.update() is called the pre update middleware is executed. What I want here is check if the name or email if they already exist. The problem is, it seems that the name and email in the pre update middleware is undefined.

My pre update middleware:

```
staffSchema.pre("update", function(next){

 var staff = this;
 Staff.find({_id:{$ne: staff.id},  $or:[{name: staff.name}, {email: staff.email}]}, function (err, docs) {

    if (!docs.length){
        next();
    }else{                
        next(new Error("Name or email already exist"));
    }
});
```

});

The result that I got is always "Name or email already exist". And I tried to print in the console log the value of staff.name but it says its undefined. Am I doing it right? Can you help me to get it working. Thank you very much guys.

Comment: Please give your question a better title, a title that describes the problem.

Comment: Your question title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. The fact you're new to Mongoose is irrelevant, and clearly it's meaningless to ask if you can get help; that's the entire purpose for the existence of this site. Your title should describe the issue clearly in a way that will make it meaningful to future readers in a search result.

Comment: Also don't use tag names in question titles. That's what tags are for. The question however lacks in detail of what you are sending in as parameter and what you actually expect should match, or not. The most likely cause is that the given conditions will always match something in your data. It's up to you to show that you think it should not. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I make sure to do it right next time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. Instead of using pre update middleware, I just create a function to check if the name or email already exist.

Here's the code:

```
module.exports.updateStaff = function(id, updatedStaff, callback){
var query = {_id: id};

//check name and email if already available
function updateStaff(id, updatedStaff, callback){
    //get staff that has the same name or email
    Staff.find({_id:{$ne:id},  $or:[{name: updatedStaff.name}, {email_pc: updatedStaff.email_pc}]}).exec(
        function(err, result){
            console.log(result);
            if(!err){
                if(result.length){                                 
                    console.log("Name or email already exist.");
                    callback("Conflict", null);
                }
                else{
                    //udpate the staff
                    Staff.update(query, updatedStaff, callback);
                }
            }else{
                callback(err);
            }

        })
}

updateStaff(id, updatedStaff, callback);
```

}

But I'm still open to answer using pre update middleware. Thanks :)

Comment: `result.length` is incorrect since `0` is actually `true`. Your correct line should be `if ( result.length > 0 )` or even more efficiently to also include a `.limit(1)` on your query so they you are not unnecessarily asking the database to return any more results than the first one found.